# WSL, phpMyAdmin, cant login

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

WSL2 and Ubuntu 20.x installed
Php 7.4 and mysql 8.x installed

mysql has users: root, phpmyadmin+pwdx, test

phpmyadmin has phpmyadmin+pwdx

sudo mysql -u username -p can be used for all three users. All of them have all permissions.

When i try to login with any of this users, i get:

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Permission denied
Verbindung für den controluser, wie er in Ihrer Konfiguration angegeben ist, ist fehlgeschlagen.

The firewall is off for the moment.

I can connect from windows with Navicat to get data from mysql.

But i really want to run phpmyadmin. Any idea, what could be the problem, please?

Answer (score 3):

In File **/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php**

change

```
$dbserver='localhost';
```

to

```
$dbserver='127.0.0.1';
```